# OWIN WebApi multiple authentications, OAuth Bearer authentication middleware

Tags: authentication, asp.net-web-api2, owin

I want to have WebApi with multiple authentications. I'm planning to enable/disable its with AuthorizeAttribute on controller's actions e.g. MyAuthOne, MyAuthTwo

Then I want to use User and work with claims.

I have appBuilder.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(xxx) in my WebApi server configurations

Problem: When request comes with valid token in request Authorization header then middleware authenticate token and set User principal.

Questions: How can I disable middleware and doesn't react to Authentification header? Maybe I have just to overwrite Principal in my filters or I do in incorrect way?

Answer (score 0):

I do not see the point, why you're using bearer authentication but don't want to use it (I think I don't understand your post quite well)

If you want to use claims, it's quite simple.

if you provide tokens created by your application you do have to provide your own ServerOptions

```
    OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions authServerOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
    {
        AllowInsecureHttp = true,
        TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/token"),
        AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(30),
        Provider = new AuthorizationServerProvider(),
    };
```

the AuthorizationServerProvider is your own implementation:

```
public class AuthorizationServerProvider : OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider
```

where you overwrite

```
public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
{
    await Task.Run(() => Login(context));
}

private void Login(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext ctx)
{
    Guid? userid = userservice.GetId(ctx.UserName, ctx.Password);
    if (userid != null)
    {
        ////here you can start with your claim stuff
        ClaimsIdentity identity = new ClaimsIdentity(new List<Claim> { new Claim("userId", userid.ToString()) }, OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType);
        identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, ctx.UserName));
        ctx.Validated(identity);
        return;
    }        
}
```

then you can use the authorization attribute

```
public class UserAuthorizationAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override bool IsAuthorized(HttpActionContext ctx)
    {
        return base.IsAuthorized(ctx) && CheckUserAuthorization(ctx.Request.GetOwinContext().Authentication);
    }

    private bool CheckUserAuthorization(IAuthenticationManager manager)
    {
        var claim = manager.User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == "user_identifier");
        if (claim != null)
        {
            Guid identifier = new Guid(claim.Value);
            //// evaluate the claim, etc...
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I have enabled appBuilder.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(). 

I have request with headers:
1. "Authorization" : "Bearer XXX"
2. "MyHeader" : "MyHeaderValue"

Then in my controller I get:
User.Identity.AuthenticationType: JWT
User.Identity.IsAythenticated: true

Why IsAythenticated is true? Does it mean that middleware validate token and set principal? Can I overwrite pricipal?

How and where I can manage User claims Principal?

Comment: My expectations with the same request:

public MyController
{

[HttpGet]
[BearerTokenAuthorize]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetCar()
{
User.Identity.AuthenticationType: JWT
User.Identity.IsAythenticated: true
}

[HttpGet]
[MyCustomAuthorize]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetBus()
{
User.Identity.AuthenticationType: MyCustom
User.Identity.IsAythenticated: true
}
}

Comment: in fact if you use owin auth it is set within the owin pipeline on authenticate stage...
https://github.com/yreynhout/katana-clone/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth/OAuthBearerAuthenticationExtensions.cs

so it's always processed if you use a authorize attribute

the authorizationprovider only creates a valid bearer token for you, which can be evaluated by our code/ or in fact sets the authe ntication to true if you use the default attribute, 

see my code, it's up to you to write your own attributes

Comment: I'd you to put the code not in the comments, generally it's quite hard to understand what you want

Answer (score 0):

I found answers for my questions:

1. I need to enable OAuth owin middleware with AuthenticationMode.Passive.
2. In my custom BeareTokenAuthenticationFilter I need call owin middleware and authenticate token:

```cs
OwinContext ctx = null;
var request = context.Request;

if (request.Properties.ContainsKey("MS_OwinContext"))
   ctx = request.Properties["MS_OwinContext"] as OwinContext;

var authenticationResult = await ctx.Authentication.AuthenticateAsync(new[] {"Bearer"})

// and I have claims in AuthenticateResult
// https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.owin.security.authenticateresult(v=vs.113).aspx
```

3. set principal context.Principal = authenticationResult...

Thank you for yours answers